Animate a Button using GSAP and SVG path
Good evening.
I've been trying to implement a button that uses a SVG path to define his shape and the subsequent animation on Hover.
I've created the animation and it works perfectly on the svg but my issue is how to mask the button with the path I created, I tried using clip-path and webkit-mask without succeding.
This is my starting svg:
<svg class="btnMain_svg" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 50 50" id="svg-draw" >
    <path class="btnMain_path" 
      d="M28.306250000000002,6.300625 L28.306250000000002,6.300625 Q49.1875,6.300625,49.1875,27.181874999999998 L49.1875,23.005625000000006 Q49.1875,43.886875,28.306250000000002,43.886875 L21.881249999999998,43.886875 Q1,43.886875,1,23.005625000000002 L1,27.181875 Q1,6.300625,21.881249999999998,6.300625 Z">
    </path>
  </svg>

Is it possible to make the svg responsive based on the button below? I'm still new to the front-end world and i'm surely overlooking something, probably something with the viewBox.
I've put everything in a codepen if someone wants to look at it and give me some tips


//hover animation
const button = document.querySelector('.btnMain');
const path = button.querySelector('.btnMain_path');

button.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  gsap.to(path, {
    duration: 0.5,
    attr: {
      d: "M41.62703713769849,4.1906966570960895 L41.62703713769849,4.1906966570960895 Q45.62536855327279,4.3062210754306705,45.815041646055,8.301721559459478 L47.42460711642001,42.20753034649664 Q47.61428020920222,46.20303083052545,43.61483202640264,46.269470525746755 L9.61135406205314,46.83434363052454 Q5.611905879253555,46.90078332574585,5.435050862774295,42.90469495045357 L3.850006567385714,7.090177447816346 Q3.6731515509064536,3.0940890725240635,7.671482966480762,3.2096134908586444 Z"
    },
    ease: "power2.out"
  });
});

button.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  gsap.to(path, {
    duration: 0.5,
    attr: {
      d: "M28.306250000000002,6.300625 L28.306250000000002,6.300625 Q49.1875,6.300625,49.1875,27.181874999999998 L49.1875,23.005625000000006 Q49.1875,43.886875,28.306250000000002,43.886875 L21.881249999999998,43.886875 Q1,43.886875,1,23.005625000000002 L1,27.181875 Q1,6.300625,21.881249999999998,6.300625 Z"
    },
    ease: "power2.out"
  });
});
.btnMain {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 10rem;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Button SVG shape path */
.btnMain_shape {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 10;
}
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="src/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="btnMain" clip-path="url(#svg-draw)" >
  HELLO
    <div class="btnMain_shape">
      <svg class="btnMain_svg" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 50 50" id="svg-draw" >
<path class="btnMain_path" 
            d="M28,6 L28,6 Q49,6,49,27 L49,23 Q49,43,28,43 L21,43 Q1,43,1,23 L1,27 Q1,6,21,6 Z">
</path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </button>
</body>



https://codepen.io/DavidMartinez76/pen/PwYJGMm
Thank in advance to anyone who replies!!

"Is it possible to make the svg responsive based on the button below" - what do you mean? Your svg path is changing on hover, so it is "responsive". Please specify what you want to achieve

What do you need the button for? Just add a click event listener to your SVG.

What I meant for "making the svg responsive based on the button" was that I want the whole component to be responsive, the animation changes the shape of the svg, I want to find a way to make it so that the dimensions of the svg depend on the dimensions of the button.
If the button has for example a longer text inside, the svg should become larger and still mask the button below.
I was looking into making the whole d="M28,6 L28,6 Q49,6,49,27 L49,23 Q49,43,28,43 L21,43 Q1,43,1,23 L1,27 Q1,6,21,6 Z" parametric and use js to do this but I feel like it's too complicated to bind the bezier curves

SVG <path> elements don't support relative units like %. You can squeeze a path to the full width/height adding preserveAspectRatio="none" attribute to the SVG but it won't keep a uniform border-radius. You may take inspiration from this post: "How to create a Squircle with a border?" explaining how to generate the path data dynamically on resize. If you can live without the smoother quadratic bezier corner rounding you may also opt for a <rect> element and animate the rx attribute

A simple way is using CSS transform:scale to fit-content.


//hover animation
    const button = document.querySelector('.btnMain');
    const path = button.querySelector('.btnMain_path');

    button.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      gsap.to(path, {
        duration: 0.5,
        attr: {
          d: "M41.62703713769849,4.1906966570960895 L41.62703713769849,4.1906966570960895 Q45.62536855327279,4.3062210754306705,45.815041646055,8.301721559459478 L47.42460711642001,42.20753034649664 Q47.61428020920222,46.20303083052545,43.61483202640264,46.269470525746755 L9.61135406205314,46.83434363052454 Q5.611905879253555,46.90078332574585,5.435050862774295,42.90469495045357 L3.850006567385714,7.090177447816346 Q3.6731515509064536,3.0940890725240635,7.671482966480762,3.2096134908586444 Z"
        },
        ease: "power2.out"
      });
    });

    button.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      gsap.to(path, {
        duration: 0.5,
        attr: {
          d: "M28.306250000000002,6.300625 L28.306250000000002,6.300625 Q49.1875,6.300625,49.1875,27.181874999999998 L49.1875,23.005625000000006 Q49.1875,43.886875,28.306250000000002,43.886875 L21.881249999999998,43.886875 Q1,43.886875,1,23.005625000000002 L1,27.181875 Q1,6.300625,21.881249999999998,6.300625 Z"
        },
        ease: "power2.out"
      });
    });
.btnMain {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 10rem;
  padding: 0 2rem; 
  color: #ffffff; 
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Button SVG shape path */
.btnMain_shape {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 10;
transform: scaleX(2); /* change to fit .txt content */
}

.txt{
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
transform: translateY(40%);
color:red;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .btnMain_shape {
transform: scaleX(1); /* change to fit .txt content */
}

.txt{
transform: translateY(44%);
font-size:8px;
}

}
<body>
 
  <button class="btnMain" clip-path="url(#svg-draw)">

    <div align="center" class="btnMain_shape">

      <svg class="btnMain_svg" stroke-width="1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 50 50" id="svg-draw" >
<path class="btnMain_path" 
            d="M28,6 L28,6 Q49,6,49,27 L49,23 Q49,43,28,43 L21,43 Q1,43,1,23 L1,27 Q1,6,21,6 Z">
</path>
      </svg>
 
    </div>

 <div class="txt" style="">HELLO</div>
                
  </button>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.1/gsap.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="src/script.js"></script>
  
  </body>
  




You don't need a library like GSAP to do an animation like that. The d attribute can be animated using a CSS transition.


button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button path {
  d: path('M 283 63 L 283 63 Q 492 63 492 272 L 492 230 Q 492 439 283 439 L 219 439 Q 10 439 10 230 L 10 272 Q 10 63 219 63 Z');
  transition: all .8s ease-out;
}

button path:hover {
  d: path('M 416 42 L 416 42 Q 456 43 458 83 L 474 422 Q 476 462 436 463 L 96 468 Q 56 469 54 429 L 39 71 Q 37 31 77 32 Z');
}
<button>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 502 502" width="100" height="100">
    <path d="M 283 63 L 283 63 Q 492 63 492 272 L 492 230 Q 492 439 283 439 L 219 439 Q 10 439 10 230 L 10 272 Q 10 63 219 63 Z" />
  </svg>
</button>




Unfortunately, Safari/webkit is still the party pooper not supporting d transitions. See caniuse stats
